# Best practices to update a collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections

This is a common topic for the majority of the developers but also a controversial one.

In my current task, I have got a `Car` which may have multiple `Image`.
The user is able to delete some of the existing images in the UI as expected and maybe add in more images

What is the best practices in those cases? Some people for example prefer to delete all the existing images of the car and then re-create the ones in the updated collection.

Any recommendations?

Comment: * I will rephrase my question

Comment: If all the images already exist in the database and have valid primary keys, you could do something like this: `$car->images()->sync($newImageIds);`

Comment: If not all exist on the database, you could first filter the existing ones and sync them like I mentioned on the first comment and then do `$car->images()->create($newImage);` for every new image.